“Cyclic components” in Batygin’s Problems in Electrodynamics

In Batygin’s collection of solved problems in electrodynamics, problem 10 (and a few others) makes reference to this “cyclic component” notation. I have never heard of this before and can’t find anything else about it online. I was hoping someone could shed some light on if these have a modern name or if they are just a historical oddity.

Never heard of cyclic component notation, but all it is the spherical basis, where the basis vectors are eigenvectors of $z$ rotations with eigenvalue $\exp(im\phi)$:
$$ R_z(\theta)\hat e_m = e^{im\phi}\hat e_m $$
for $m=(-1,0,1)$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis

This is exactly what I was looking for!
